# Details despite NDA for selling company (California)

Tags: united-states, california, non-disclosure

[This question](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/94070/51266) says that it may be possible that an NDA can exist such that if someone were to sell their company, can they can have an NDA that prevents them from speaking about their company name, the buying company's name, and details about what their company does. Would it be possible to find out any of these details as a third party despite the NDA? For example, I've heard that one can look up if an LLC existed for 3 years beyond the LLC's closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the seller of a company signed an NDA, that NDA would make it illegal *for them* to tell you whatever the NDA covers (except there may be legal requirements that would override an NDA).

That doesn't mean you cannot find out in any other legal way. For example, the company's accountant most likely knows a lot of things, and if they didn't sign an NDA, they may be free to tell you. Obviously the government will know things, as you said, the company had to be registered, the sale had to be registered, and you can't just close a company down and make it disappear. Especially since any obligations of the company will continue to exist for many years.

Say the company in question bought office furniture from you and was supposed to pay in 60 monthly installments. Selling the company doesn't stop that, closing the company down won't stop that, signing an NDA won't stop that. You will still be able to find the company and make them pay.

Comment: Not illegal, simply a breech of contract